# Ubuntu 13.04 HDMI resolution and display options incorrect

Tags: xorg, display, resolution, intel-graphics, hdmi

I have installed ubuntu 13.04 and the HDMI resolution is incorrect and options limited to a max of 1280x720. The VGA is not perfect as it is cutting off the top taskbar slightly, it also shows a resolution of 1360x768 instead of 1366x768.

System specs: Intel Celeron 847, NM70 chipset with integrated graphics. The display is my 32" Samsung LCD TV with a max resolution of 1366x768.

In the display options it is picking up the incorrect display information. The VGA output displays a 19" while the HDMI picks up a 7".

I have read in a fourum that it has to do possible with incorrect EDID information from the display and you need to change the xorg.conf file with the line:

Option "UseEDID" "False"

But 13.04 doesn't come with an xorg.conf file anymore?

Is this the correct and best way to resolve this and if so how?

Answer (score 2):

I did some more searching and came across this page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution . This is the part that helped me :)

Adding undetected resolutions
Due to buggy hardware or drivers, your monitor's correct resolutions may not always be detected. For example, the EDID data block queried from your monitor may be incorrect.

If the mode already exists, but just isn't associated for the particular output, you can add it like this:

$ xrandr --addmode S-video 800x600

If the mode doesn't yet exist, you'll need to create it first by specifying a modeline:

$ xrandr --newmode

You may create a modeline using the gtf or cvt utility. For example, if you want to add a mode with resolution 800x600 at 60 Hz, you can enter the following command: (The output is shown following.)

$ cvt 800 600 60

# 800x600 59.86 Hz (CVT 0.48M3) hsync: 37.35 kHz; pclk: 38.25 MHz
Modeline "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync

Then copy the information after the word "Modeline" into the xrandr command:

$ xrandr --newmode "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync

After the mode is entered, it needs to be added to the output using the --addmode command as explained above.

I'm not sure if its a driver issue but I see that my sounds not either working on my TV via the HDMI and it does not pick up the HDMI sound driver in the sound settings.